# Conditions inside Select clause in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method that gets a list of objects and then returns all their properties values based on the attributes and types of the property.
 I'm having difficulties with selecting the value because the **Select** depends on conditions.
 What I did so far allows me to get the value in the ugliest way I have ever seen:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetValues(List<ProperyInfo> objects)
{
     var allValues = new List<string>();
     foreach (var obj in objects)
     {
         // Get the PropertyInfo for the obj
         var properties = GetPropertiesWithTheAttributes(obj);
         var values = properties.Select(x => new 
             {
             Value = x.GetValue(obj, null) == null
                         ?  string.empty
                         :
                         x.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum)
                         ? Convert.ToInt32(x.GetValue(obj, null)).ToString()
                         : (x.GetValue(obj, null)).ToString(),
             ((ReportAttribute)
             Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(ReportAttribute), false)).Order
             })
             .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
             .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
             .ToList();

             allValues.AddRange(values);
    }

    return allValues;
}
```

And in the code I published here I even removed the check for the DisplayDate property in the ReportAttribute, which verifies if the datetime property of the attribute would be displayed as date or datetime...

**serenity now!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply extract this into 2 methods, and get rid of the ternary operator:

```
    // not sure how to name 'obj' and 'x' without more context
    private static object GetValue(PropertyInfo obj, PropertyInfo x)
    {
        if (x.GetValue(obj, null) == null) return string.Empty;

        if (x.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof (Enum))
            return Convert.ToInt32(x.GetValue(obj, null));

        return x.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    private static int GetOrder(PropertyInfo x)
    {
        return ((ReportAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(ReportAttribute), false)).Order;
    }
```

So you can write:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValues(List<PropertyInfo> objects)
    {
        var allValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            // Get the PropertyInfo for the obj 
            var properties = GetPropertiesWithTheAttributes(obj);
            var values = properties.Select(x => new
                                                    {
                                                        Value = GetValue(obj, x),
                                                        Order = GetOrder(x)
                                                    })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
                .ToList();

            allValues.AddRange(values);
        }

        return allValues;
    }
```

If you really want to inline this, you can change the lambda expression in your `Select` to a statement:

```
.Select(x =>
            {
                object value;
                if (x.GetValue(obj, null) == null) value = string.Empty;
                else if (x.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof (Enum))
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(x.GetValue(obj, null));
                else value = x.GetValue(obj, null);

                return new
                            {
                                Value = value,
                                ((ReportAttribute)
                                Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof (ReportAttribute), false)).
                                    Order
                            };
            })
```

Comment: +1 That indeed solve the problem! thanks, but is there a way to write conditions inside if statment? add the answer and I will mark as accepted answer. thanks again.

Comment: you can change the lambda expression to a statement (see edit), but I would not recommend it. A seperate method seems more readable and easier to debug for sure.

Comment: No I don't want to inline it, only for the knowledge... thanks again.