# Entity Framework condition in select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following database code:

```
static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(bool withchildren) {
    using (var model = new testEntities()) {
        var res = default(IQueryable<dynamic>);
        if (withchildren) {
            res = model.UserSet
                .Where(u => u.name != "")
                .Select(u => new {
                    Name = u.name,
                    Email = u.email,
                    Groups = u.GroupSet.Select(g => new {
                        Name = g.name,
                        Id = g.Id
                    })
                });
        } else {
            res = model.UserSet
                .Where(u => u.name != "")
                .Select(u => new {
                    Name = u.name,
                    Email = u.email
                });
        }
        return res.ToList()
    }
}
```

I would like to shrink the code and write it like this:

```
static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(bool withchildren) {
    using (var model = new testEntities()) {
        var res = default(IQueryable<dynamic>);
        res = model.UserSet
            .Where(u => u.name != "")
            .Select(u => {
                dynamic item = new { 
                    Name = u.name,
                    Email = u.email
                };
                if(withchildren) {
                    item.Groups = u.GroupSet.Select(g => new {
                        Name = g.name,
                        Id = g.Id
                    });
                }
                return item;
            });
        return res.ToList();
    }
}
```

But Visual Studio complains, that it cannot convert the lambda expression into an expression tree.

My question is, is there a way to accomplish that with the Entity Framework and Linq? I really wouldn't want to use ADO.net directly.

Maybe there is even a better version to shrink it, than the code that I imagine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253905/conditions-inside-select-clause-in-linq) is a related question with Linq-To-Objects.

#### EDIT

Before someone asks, I use `dynamic` in the example code to make it a bit easier and faster.

#### EDIT 2

My goal with this approach is, to only query the fields I need to improve performance. Check http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Slow-Performance-Is-it-the-Entity-Framework-or-you.aspx.

At the moment we use something like

```
static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(bool withchildren) {
    using (var model = new testEntities()) {
        var res = default(IQueryable<dynamic>);
        res = model.UserSet
            .Where(u => u.name != "")
            .ToList();
        return res;
    }
}
```

And the performance is, according to Glimpse, horrible.

#### EDIT 3

Short side note, I made up some quick and dirty code. That is, why the `foreach` at the end was not needed. The actual code is not available at the moment.

Comment: What if you use the conditional operator `Groups = !withchildren ? null : u.GroupSet.Select....`?

Comment: @juharr: Well, that seems good, see the answer of [JLRishe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27707381/1126393)

Comment: Do you know for sure this is your performance problem? Do you need to retrieve the entire table here? Perhaps you can use paging or filter your data before retrieving them?

Comment: @RobTillie I used Glimpse to check for that. And yes, the database access is the bottle neck. For that purpose I googled a bit and found, that you can increase performance by just selecting the needed fields.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you couldn't use:

```
res = model.UserSet
    .Where(u => u.name != "")
    .Select(u =>  new { 
            Name = u.name,
            Email = u.email,
            Groups = withchildren 
                ? u.GroupSet.Select(g => new {
                     Name = g.name,
                     Id = g.Id
                  })
                : null;
            })
        };
```

or perhaps:

```
res = model.UserSet
    .Where(u => u.name != "")
    .ToList()                        // ToList() here to enumerate the items
    .Select(u => {
        dynamic item = new { 
            Name = u.name,
            Email = u.email
        };
        if(withchildren) {
            item.Groups = u.GroupSet.Select(g => new {
                Name = g.name,
                Id = g.Id
            });
        }
        return item;
    });
```

One approach that would allow you to eliminate *some* code would be:

```
var res = model.UserSet.Where(u => u.name != "");
if (withchildren) {
    res = res.Select(u => new {
             Name = u.name,
             Email = u.email,
             Groups = u.GroupSet.Select(g => new {
                Name = g.name,
                Id = g.Id
             })
          });
} else {
    res = res.Select(u => new {
            Name = u.name,
            Email = u.email
        });
}
```

Comment: The second part is not ok, because I want to reduce the execution time of the database queries and I want to shorten the queries generated by EF. The first option looks good :)

Comment: @Knerd I see. Makes sense. Just a question - isn't the `foreach` loop at the end of your method redundant? Can't you return `res` directly?

Comment: Let me work through my code... Just a quick thing, the actual code is at home on a different computer, so I made some code quick and dirty up ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most requested by community feature is support of multi-line expressions in EF,
however so far, you can use only conditional operator "?:" as well as wrap result in
one common type, so both your results will have to have "Groups" field.

Also there are an extensions to linq-providers such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/ ,
however they are based on own conventions so any developer should study it in depth before
taking advance in applying and supporting code written upon that extensions.